# Add Sort Link in Custom Post Type List

Tags: admin, sort

I need to add a link here, beside the Published link:

[image]

How can I do it? I'm trying to filter my custom post type by meta values and need a link to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Already got it:

```
add_action( 'views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views' );
function remove_edit_post_views( $views ) {
        $views['pre'] = '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.admin_url().'edit.php?yourlink">Name of Sort</a>';
        return $views;
}
```

Thanks!